# Bash function returning blank

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have following function that calculates the time for execution of command in milliseconds

```
function execute_command(){
  #Calculate the execution time for the command $1
  exec 3>&1 4>&2
  exec_time=$( { time $@ 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 )
  exec 3>&- 4>&-
  RES=$(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%d\",${exec_time}*1000}")
  echo $RES
}
remove_java7_latency=$(execute_command "yum -y remove java7" | tail -n 1)
echo "remove_java7_latency=${remove_java7_latency}" >> /tmp/sampleoutput
```

But when I check the `sampleoutput` it is shown as

```
remove_java7_latency=
```

If I redirect RES in the function to the same file like

```
echo "RES=${RES}" >> /tmp/sampleoutput
```

It is coming fine as `RES=1630.00`

Can someone help me to understand why is this not working for return values? What is correct way to return value in this case? I am not inclined to use bc utility because the underlying instance does not have it installed by default.

Comment: If the `RES` redirection redirection works, could the problem come from the `| tail -n1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exec_time was infact producing multi line output.
Solution is to replace

```
exec_time=$( { time $@ 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 )
```

with

```
exec_time=$( { time $@ 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 | tail -n 1)
```